# Error 400 in axios when i try connect to Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, axios

hi i'm trying to do a login in html and send the user and password with axios to @RestController and @PostMapping, in this moment, i get response to server but the problem is the response in the client because i get error 400 when i try print in the log the response.

Axios:

```
var url = 'rest/loginParametros';
axios.post(url, {
    user: this.username,
    password: this.password
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
 });
```

RequestMapping

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class RestController {

private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RestController.class);

@PostMapping("/loginParametros")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> loginParametros(@RequestParam(value = "user", required = true) String user, 
                    @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password)
{
    log.info("user: " + user + " password: " + password);
    if(user.equals("hitzu") && password.equals("hitzu"))
        return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Also, when consume the restService with postman i get the response

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu1UY.png)

Comment: have you checked that you are actually sending user and password? it could be that your js variables are not set by the time you do the post (this.username and this.password). One way to easily check this: just replace those variables with hardcoded valid username and password as a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username/password you send with Axios are part of the request payload (will be accessible with `@RequestBody` on Spring side).

If you want to get your code working, you have to pass username/password as query string.

```
var url = 'rest/loginParametros?user=' + this.username + '&password=' + this.password;
```

But I don't recommend to use this due to security.

You should use `@RequestBody` with a `UserInfo` class that contains 2 `String` fields (user, password) instead of your `@RequestParam`s.